# Axios mock request issue

Tags: typescript, axios, jestjs, mocking, nestjs

I have this Axios request and need make the coverage using jest, but i can't.

jest version: 27.2.5
axios version: 0.25.0
nestJS version: 8.2.5

index.js

```
await axios
        .get('url_here', {
            headers: {
                'user-id': userId,
            },
        })
        .then(function (res) {
                return res.data;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            throw new NotFoundException(err.response.data);
        });
```

index.spec.js

```
describe('When to call group service', () => {
    let service: TestService;

    jest.mock('axios');
    const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution using part of this post:

https://www.csrhymes.com/2022/03/09/mocking-axios-with-jest-and-typescript.html

first step:
need use `jest.mock('axios')` out of any describe in the beginning of test file.

second step:
it's necessary use this mock function with typeof to work correctly
at test file
`const mockedAxios = axios jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios>`

third step:
now need create a mocked request response following this properties model to work !
at test file

```
const resp = {
    data: [{ id: 1, nickname: 'teste' }],
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'Ok',
    headers: {},
    config: {},
};
```

fourth step:
defining the response of our mock
at test file

```
mockedAxios.mockResolvedValueOnce(resp);
```

and finally, need refactor the initial axios request to this:
index file

```
await axios('url_here', {
          method: 'GET'
          headers: {
             'user-id': userId,
          },
      })
        .then(function (res) {
             return res.data;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
             throw new NotFoundException(err.response.data);
        });
```

changing the call function .get to use static definition of method as a property, cause before i received the error .than it isn't defined

sorry for my mistakes cause this it's my first time writing something here in stackoverflow.